# How to use Get-CimObject and Get-WMIObject in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi

I want to solidify my understanding of `Get-CimClass` and `Get-CimInstance`. `Get-Cimclass` will show you what is available and `Get-CimInstance` will process and retrieve the information.

The Reason I ask is I want to get information for the product Powershell is being run on. I would think a simple code like below would give it, but I get no output or error from powershell.

Could you please point in in the right direction? Thanks.

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Product
```

Comment: Ok so I think this is down to how im logging in, I use a VM for Server 2018, which logs in at C;\Users\Administrator> but on my pc it goes into  C:\Windows\system32 and this command works. Im guessin that location is key ?

Comment: No, current working directory is irrelevant to Get-CIMInstance. The problem may be permissions-related. Does the account you're using have Admin access to your Server 2018 instance? Does Get-CIMInstance work on your desktop Windows machine within an elevated powershell instance?

Comment: on my own desktop Windows 10 system, `GetCimInstance -classname Win32_product` does work within an elevated powerShell instance. It does, though, take a long time to complete, as it seems to be enumerating every installed product on the system. As long as you're just experimenting, try other classes, like `Win32_OperatingSystem`

Comment: Fyi, win32_product is broken and should be avoided. Check your appliction events after querying this class and you'll see what I mean : it forces a consistency check on all registered MSI packages (which can break some applications on rare occassions)